# Google Visualization - Dashboard with Bubble Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to create a dashboard that will be displayed on a webpage.  I understand how this works for controls with pie/column/bar charts, but I cannot figure out how to do this for a bubble chart.

I can create a bubble chart by itself, I just cannot add the controls so that my users can manipulate the data.  Is this possible for Bubble charts?  If so, how?

Comment: Bubble charts work exactly the same as the other charts.  If you could edit your answer to include the code you have tried that isn't working, we might be able to help you get it working.

Comment: I figured it out...so indirectly your post helped!  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chris, could you add your solution and accept the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the jsfiddle with a category filter control:

http://jsfiddle.net/vYMyz/9/

In the ChartWrapper object, the 'ChartType' should be 'BubbleChart':

```
var myChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                   chartType: 'BubbleChart',
                   containerId: ...
```